# SetState is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Probably doing something stupid, but if anybody can help. I think this is undefined or something. So im trying to use setState and getting the following error.

> line 20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';

class TimeoutModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeLeft: 60,
      timeoutModal: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() =>{
      this.setState({ timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft - 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({timeoutModal: false});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.timeoutStatus);
    return (
      <div className="timeout-modal">
        <div className="timeout-modal__container">
          <p>Would you like to continue? {this.state.timeLeft}</p>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="timeout-modal__container-button">Yes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimeoutModal;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the `handleClick` event with current component instance. So change the `onChange` event handler as.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className="timeout-modal__container-button">Yes</button>
```

From the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to onClick, this will be **undefined**
>   when the function is actually called.

Much cleaner when you bind them inside the contructor function and then use them.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    timeLeft: 60,
    timeoutModal: true
  };
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
```

Write the handler now.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick} className="timeout-modal__container-button">Yes</button>
```

Comment: Spot on mate, works perfect. Knew it was something stupid. Mucho gracias (++A)

Comment: @AdamDodds Please read the link I gave in the post. It will be helpful in future if you read it once from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({timeoutModal: false});
  }
```

You should use arrow functions to have `this` working properly inside your function

Comment: With this approach, u no more need *arrow* function when adding them to handler props.

Comment: Yes, but the definition of function stays the same and avoids to add a new line in the constructor to bind this. You maybe would like to read that piece of article https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#arrow-functions it explains really well

Comment: The syntax you wrote is not yet standard. Although everybody using it with babel, even me. I have no problem with this style. What I said, when you write this syntax, no need to write `onClick={() => this.handleClick}` anymore. We can use this style, or the `.bind()` approach. In both we need no more `() => ()` with event handlers.

Comment: Yes we agree :)